# How can I cache/save the filter search input values in the Azure Cosmos DB online view?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

How can I cache/save the filter search input values in the Azure Cosmos DB online view?

E.g. I have the three cached values:

```
WHERE c.id = "foo"
ORDER BY c._ts DESC
WHERE c.id = "foo" ORDER BY c._ts DESC
```

How could I remove some of these values and how could I add more values?

Also, it seems these values will be shown for everyone who is using that database view (on my team everybody has the same three autocompletion options). I somehow added them when I just joined the team, but now I have no idea how to manage them.

[image]

Comment: You didn't cache these. They are hardcoded into the data explorer as examples https://github.com/search?q=repo%3AAzure%2Fcosmos-explorer%20c._ts%20DESC&type=code